# How to make interpolation print data?

Tags: javascript, interpolation

```js
let Big = 11243566n;
console.log (' ${Big}  ${typeof Big}.');
```

The console says:

```
${Big} ${typeof Big}.
```

How to make it to print

```
11243566 [BigInt]
```

or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `` ` ``  instead of single quotes:

```js
let Big = 11243566n;
console.log (` ${Big} ${typeof Big}.`);
```